# Как изменить название файлов имеющих пробел по регулярному выражению (.bat)?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

**Доброго времени суток.**

Есть много файлов в папке таких как:

Т1253663   .jpg 
Т1253632 .jpg 
Т125362 .jpg 
Т125362.jpg

**Задача заключается в том, что через bat нужно переименовать 

эти файлы, так чтобы они были совсем без пробелов.**

Я особо не понимаю bat, поэтому вопрос к вам знатоки) 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня прибор не понимает пробелы в файлах, поэтому приходится часто запускать такой скрипт (он удаляет все пробелы в именах файлов):

```
:renameNoSpace  [/R]  [FolderPath]
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if /i "%~1"=="/R" (
  set "forOption=%~1 %2"
  set "inPath="
) else (
  set "forOption="
  if "%~1" neq "" (set "inPath=%~1\") else set "inPath="
)
for %forOption% %%F in ("%inPath%* *") do (
  if /i "%~f0" neq "%%~fF" (
    set "folder=%%~dpF"
    set "file=%%~nxF"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
    ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Использование: назовите его, допустим, delspaces.bat, и используйте так:

```
delspaces.bat [без аргументов]: работает в текущем каталоге  
delspaces.bat /R : переименовывает файлы во всём дереве папок, начиная с текущей  
delspaces.bat папка : переименовывает файлы в каталоге "папка", найденном в текущем каталоге  
delspaces.bat "c:\my folder\" : Переименовывает файлы по указанному пути
```

Comment: Тоже такая же фигня с прибором :) Только файлов обычно мало, ручками всё, ручками :)

Answer (score 2):

А если я делаю переименование на машине, где есть powershell, то использую такой скрипт:

```
dir |
Where-Object { $_.name.Contains(" ") } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace " ","" }
```

Я понимаю, что это не BAT, но работает весьма быстрее. Чтобы использовать, сохраните как имя_файла.ps1, а затем правый клик - запустить.

Comment: А почему быстрее? Powershell всегда быстрее, чем BAT-интерпретатор?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Вроде бы да, читал где-то. В любом случае, там где запускаю PS, там машина новее и диски быстрее :)

Comment: Это немного странно, пойду гуглить почему PS быстрее :)